# Can a "rage quit" link be added to allow suspended users to delete their accounts?

Tags: feature-request, account-suspension, deleted-accounts

According to the [delete-account help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account), users are required to put the text "please delete me" in their profile's "about me" text. But a suspended user can not edit their profile, so they are unable to follow the required process.

Often enough, a suspended user feels so vengeful that they have a burning desire to [rage quit](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ragequit) by deleting their account, but alas they can not while suspended.

It would be good to support such users to fulfil their desires by providing a *rage quit* link that appears only for suspended users:

[image: rage quit]

By the way, there is some basis for this question. I had a request for "how to delete my account" from a recently-suspended user.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prisoner_suicide

Comment: Oh come on... I really thought this was funny!

Comment: Not sure if trolling.

Comment: @michaelb958: Well it is true that suspended users are unable to edit their profiles.

Comment: You're about 2 weeks late with a post like this. #antijokechicken

Comment: We don't want to allow the suspended user any form of satisfaction. Otherwise why would we vengefully suspend people in the first place?

Comment: @michaelb958 I had a question from a suspended users wanting to know how he could delete his account, and I thought of this.

Comment: @Bohemian I think this might be better received if you didn't call it _rage-quit_ as this just sounds like a joke and not a real feature request.

Comment: @bluefeet Indeed, for a true rage quit button it should really add swearing to all their posts, post a rant on meta and start calling all moderators neckbeards

Comment: @bluefeet It *is* a joke. For the occasional real need, a message to a moderator does the job already.

Comment: It's now possible for suspended users to request deletion of their accounts, as it's all automated now: [How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason for this requirement is to ensure that the person requesting the deletion *is actually the owner of the account*. Since logged in suspended users *can* write replies to moderator messages (no one *but* them and moderators can), they can provide this bit of proof there, by simply writing the text in a reply.

The chances of someone actually *seeing* that on Stack Overflow aren't that great, so they should follow up with us via the contact form. Just make sure to indicate that you've put the 'delete me' text in a reply to the mod message you received upon your suspension.

However, be careful - we might inform you that we'll proceed with your deletion, but you might not be welcome to return to the site if you don't wait out your suspension. It depends on the circumstances.

Comment: By the way, there is some basis for this question. I had a request for "how to delete my account" from a recently-suspended user.

Comment: Just send those folks to [/contact](http://stackoverflow.com/contact) - it's a pretty regular thing we get. _Most_ of the time our reply is going to be "*Okay, we'll do it, but you won't be welcome back for a period of time - just keep that in mind.*"