# Allow suspended users to request account deletion

Tags: feature-request, account-suspension, deleted-accounts

Currently, it seems that suspended accounts are unable to request account deletion.

This should be changed to make it possible.

If someone wants to leave, there's no point prolonging the drama by making them wait.

If necessary, increase the [Cooling off](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151874/delay-user-requests-for-account-deletion-by-24-hours) period for account deletion from 24 hours to 48 hours, because people may be in an especially bad mood if they're being suspended.

[Can a "rage quit" link be added to allow suspended users to delete their accounts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229562/can-a-rage-quit-link-be-added-to-allow-suspended-users-to-delete-their-account) is a similar proposal, but it seemed to be a [joke proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229562/can-a-rage-quit-link-be-added-to-allow-suspended-users-to-delete-their-account#comment753790_229562), and was downvoted.

Comment: Nevertheless, this is still a dupe of the other post, and Tim's answer applies. The point is to prove you own the account and a moderator message reply does that too.