# Missing option to delete account

Tags: bug, deleted-accounts

I'm trying to delete [my account](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/20963/pbxman) from the [*Politics* Stack Exchange site](https://politics.stackexchange.com/tour), because I don't think this network is suited for it. Then again when I go to:

[image: Profile]
[image: 404]

I don't want to receive any messages from this network again and I don't want to add Stack Exchange to my [Robinson list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_list) or as spam.

What can I do?

**UPDATE**

The question is different to the delete my acount one because the option to remove my profile wasn't there and I was getting a page with a 404 code.

Comment: Sorry, I see you just hid it. Please be more clear where exactly you see that "404" message? Anyway, while suspended you can't delete your account. There is no bug.

Comment: See this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229562/can-a-rage-quit-link-be-added-to-allow-suspended-users-to-delete-their-account

Comment: I did not hide anything. a 404 is a bug! I'll wait until that suspension is finished. For now I won't remove all my profiles maybe in the future.
Thanks

Comment: Even if you're suspended, you should be able to navigate to [this page](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/delete/current) and schedule your account for deletion (cf. [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7979)).

Comment: @ShadowThePrincessWizard well i'm not... I'll wait 7 days to remove my account thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to access the account deletion page [thru this link](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/delete/current).

If that doesn't work for you, use the [Contact Us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) form. One of the available topics there is "I need to delete my user profile".

---

**Note**: should you want to delete ALL your profiles, be aware that the account deletion page only deletes your profile on a specific site, so if you have multiple profiles you need to delete each one individually from each site. Depending on how many profiles you have, you may want to use the Contact Us option anyway - but beware that option generally takes a little longer to complete.
Also, as Shadow mentioned, keep in mind that if you are suspended you can't delete the profile (that is probably to avoid user getting out of a suspension by deleting and recreating the profile).

Answer (score 2):

## This doesn't appear to be a bug

According to [How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account/7979#7979):

> **Suspended users**: If you are suspended, ***you will get an error message*** when opening the Edit Profile page because you cannot edit your profile while suspended.

You can still delete your account on politics.SE [here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/delete/current) or by sending a message to the Team using the [Contact Us form](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact).

> **You can still access the Delete Profile subpage though**, either through the help center article, by selecting the "I need to delete my user profile" option on the contact page, or by navigating to `/users/delete/current` on the site you want to delete your account.

Note that  you'll have to delete all your site accounts individually if you want to delete more than one.

Comment: your link worked. I was still getting that 404.

Comment: @PbxMan Yeah it looks like the 404 is by design.

Comment: nothing like adding insult to injury :/